# Background process killing with Parent process in C

Tags: c, process, operating-system

I have the following code in my main function

```
pid_t pid;
pid = fork(); //Two processes are made

if (pid > 0 && runBGflag==0) //Parent process. Waits for child termination and prints exit status
{
    int status;
    if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == pid && WIFEXITED(status))
    {
        printf("Exitstatus [");
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfTokens; i++)
        {
            printf("%s ", commands[i]);
        }
        printf("\b] = %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
}
else if (pid == 0)  //Child process. Executes commands and prints error if something unexpected happened
{
     if (runBGflag==1) insertElement(getpid(),ptr);
     execvp(commands[0], commands);
     printf ("exec: %s\n", strerror(errno));
     exit(1);
}
```

In a nutshell, a child process is made and if the runBackGround flag is set, the parent process will not wait for the child process to exit, but rather continue running. If a background process is made, the PID of the background process is stored in a list. At a later point, this function is called

```
void delete_zombies(void)
{
    pid_t kidpid;
    int status;
    char buffer[1337];
 


    while ((kidpid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0)
    {
        removeElement(kidpid,buffer,1337);
        printf("Child %ld terminated\n", kidpid);
        printf("its command was %s\n",buffer);
    }
}
```

This function simply checks if any child processes have died and in that case deletes them. It will then search for the childs PID in the list, remove it and print it out.

The problem is, the delete_zombies function will find that a child has died and will then try to remove it from the list, but it only finds an empty list, as if the child process never inserted its PID into the list.

This is really strange, because delete_zombies only finds a dead child process, when there was one created with the background flag set, so we know insertElement must have been called, but strangely when the parent checks in the list nothing is there

Is the cause for that, that child process and parent process have seperate lists, or is the PID maybe wrong?

Comment: *that child process and parent process have seperate lists* Unless you're using shared memory, yes.

Comment: Since they have separate lists, the parent will have to insert the child's PID into its list. This PID is returned by `fork()` within the parent process.